# CSS problem with Firefox 4 & 5

Tags: css, firefox, firefox4

I have a problem with this page: http://www.liraprint.com/knigi

Books are not shown as they have to be - they are moved in the right. The problem is only in Firefox 4 & 5. In 3.6 it's ok as in all other browsers.

I think it's the .browse_product_image_body{ float:left; } that has something to do with this. Or maybe I'm missing something...Can you help me to fix this, please?

Here is a screenshot **[screenshot](http://www.liraprint.com/demo.png)** of the problem.

```
.browse_product_page{
width:547px;
}
.browse_product_header{ 
margin-top:0px;
}
.browse_product_title_background{
width:547px;
height: 40px;
background-image: url(images/product-title-background-tile.png);
margin-top: 0px;
border:1px solid #DBDBDB;
border-top-left-radius:3px;
-moz-border-top-left-radius:3px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */  
border-top-right-radius:3px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius:3px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */ 
}
.browse_product_title{
font-size:24px;
padding:12px 0 0 4px;
float:left;
text-decoration:none;
}
.browse_product_name{
font-size:18px;
padding:12px 0 0 4px;
text-decoration:none;
}
.browse_product_author_body{
width:244px;
height:29px;
float:right;
margin:0 0px 10px 0;
background-image:url(images/author_background.png);
}
.browse_product_author{
font-size:13px;
padding:4px 0 0 0;
margin:0;
font-weight:bold;
}
.browse_product_body{
width:547px;
height:234px;
margin:-20px 0 10px 0;
border:1px solid #DBDBDB;
border-top:1px;
border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius:3px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */   
border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius:3px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */  }

.browse_product_image_body{
  float:left;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; 
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.browse_product_image{
width:123px;
height:190px;
margin:0px 2px 2px 2px; 
padding:2px;
}
.browse_product_description{
width:auto;
height:96px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0; 
padding:70px 10px 10px 10px;
text-align:justify;
}
.browse_product_price_body{
width:40px;
float:left;
padding: 0px 0 0 0px;
}
.browse_product_price{
font-size:14px;
text-align:left;
font-weight:bold;
}
.browse_product_price_value{
margin-top:-16px;
margin-left:46px;
margin-right:-75px;
}
.browse_product_read_more{
height:30px;
background-image:url(images/browse_read_more.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin:0px 47px 0 404px;
padding:5px 0px 0 0;
}
.browse_product_read_more_link{
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't got an answer for you, but if it helps, I am using Firefox 5.0 and the website looks [fine](http://i.imgur.com/SReTg.jpg) (i.e. not like the screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the problem. It seems that not only the image container `.browse_product_image_body`, but the inside div `.browse_product_image` has to be set to `float:left`, too.